# Yahoo Local Search API Is Not Working At All

Tags: php, web-services, api, yahoo, yahoo-api

All queries performed at: http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch? are timing out.

I have not been able to find any documentation explaining this down-time or changes to the API.

Our app uses this API, and this is a significant loss.

I didn't expect it to be so difficult finding information about this issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after prodding around the net I found that all documentation from the `Yahoo Developer Network` has been pulled.

Here's a quote from their [Blog](http://yahoo.tumblr.com/062813)

`Earlier this year, we announced an ongoing effort to sharpen our focus and deliver experiences that enhance your daily lives. As part of that, today we’re shutting down a few products so we can continue to focus on creating beautiful products that are essential to you every day.`

`Yahoo! Local API (September 28, 2013) -- As part of this shutdown, all Yahoo! Local API documentation will also be removed from the Yahoo! Developer Network portal.`

Needless to say, this is rather significant.  This API was a large part of our application, and provides reviews and ratings of companies across the country.  I am not a fan of this one bit.

Comment: Tell me about it, I'm dealing with this right now, I can't believe that they don't even return a 500 error or something, that is such bullshit to not tell anyone your shutting down a service, and also just let all their servers timeout waiting for a response... LAME.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem soon. 
Since then, keep the following link
http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/
but not sure that he still active.

The important part is 
***We are shutting down this service on September 13, 2011. We suggest using maps from our partner Nokia. Please visit [developer.here.net](http://developer.here.net)  for more information.***

Hope this will help...